# how to loop inside a jquery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeline

I am working on a script that takes some records from the server and puts it on a timeline. The timeline script uses jQuery, raphael and qtip to generate a timeline. A dot on the timeline shows the event. this dot is put on the timeline. Since I have some records which are dots to be put on the timeline, I not able to loop the "dates" by keeping the year,month and date as variables.

The records returns the date, month, and year, along with the name of the record.

This is the original code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      var events = [
      {dates: [new Date(2012, 4, 5)], title: "some name", section: 0}
      ];

      var timeline1 = new Chronoline(document.getElementById("target1"), events,
        {animated: true,
         tooltips: true,
         defaultStartDate: new Date(2012, 3, 5),
         sections: sections,
         sectionLabelAttrs: {'fill': '#997e3d', 'font-weight': 'bold'},
          draggable: true
      });

});
```

So i thought of this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var events = [

  for (var i = 0; i < totalrecordsretreived; i++)
  {
     var x,y,z, recname;

     recname = retrievedrecord[i].name;
     x = retrievedrecord[i].day;
     y = retrievedrecord[i].month;
     z = retrievedrecord[i].year;

    //code for putting record into x,y,z and recname

    {dates: [new Date(z, y, x)], title: recname, section: 0} // creates the dot.
  }

  ];

  var timeline1 = new Chronoline(document.getElementById("target1"), events,
    {animated: true,
     tooltips: true,
     defaultStartDate: new Date(2012, 3, 5),
     sections: sections,
     sectionLabelAttrs: {'fill': '#997e3d', 'font-weight': 'bold'},
      draggable: true
  });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using http://stoicloofah.github.io/chronoline.js/ for the Chronoline?

Also it is not quite clear what is your question.

Comment: @ZlatinZlatev - Yes i am using chronoline.js. I am trying to plot many  dots [events] on the timeline. To make multiple dots on timeline i wanted to use a loop. This loop takes one record at a time, and puts it in the events -> "dates : [new Date(z,y,x)]...".

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see...

Change your code to:

```
  var events = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < totalrecordsretreived; i++)
  {
     var x,y,z, recname;

     recname = retrievedrecord[i].name;
     x = retrievedrecord[i].day;
     y = retrievedrecord[i].month;
     z = retrievedrecord[i].year;

    //code for putting record into x,y,z and recname

    events.push({dates: [new Date(z, y, x)], title: recname, section: 0}); // creates the dot.
  }
```

Basically what the code above does is create an empty Array events. And then utilize the push method of Array class to fill it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: OK, could you check the value of events array after the loop for me? You could for example use console.log(JSON.stringify(events)) right after the loop.